# How to copy the connections from Child case to Parent case in MS-Dynamics CRM 2015 online using Plug-In

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to create the plug-in for copying connection records from child case to parent case using plug-in. I written code as below. Retrieved the connections from child case. Copy those connections to parent case.

```c
private static EntityCollection GetConnectionList(IOrganizationService service, EntityReference childCase)
    {
        EntityCollection eColl = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression("<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
               "<entity name='incident'>" +
               "<attribute name='incidentid' />" +
               "<filter type='and'>" +
               "<condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />" +
               "<condition attribute='incidentid' operator='eq' value='" + childCase.Id + "' />" +
               "</filter>" +
               "<link-entity name ='connection' from='record1id' to='incidentid'> "+
               "<filter type='and'>" +
               "<condition attribute='record2id' operator='not-null' />" +
               "<condition attribute='record2roleid' operator='eq' uiname='Witness' uitype='connectionrole' value={16DA474E-EC82-E511-8100-3863BB35FDE0} />" +
               "<condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' /> " +
               "</filter>" +
               "</link-entity>" +
               "</entity>" +
               "</fetch>"));
        return eColl;
    }

//calling above methods in main method...
// Get the connection records from the child cases
EntityCollection connectionColl = GetConnectionList(service, childCaseRef);

// Create copy of connection to link FTP prosecution case
CreateCloneOfConnections(connectionColl, service, childCaseRef, parentCaseRef, context);

private static void CreateCloneOfConnections(EntityCollection connectionColl, IOrganizationService service, EntityReference childCaseRef, EntityReference parentCaseRef, IPluginExecutionContext context)
    {
        foreach (Entity connection in connectionColl.Entities)
        {
            Entity newEntity = Utility.CloneEntity(connection);

            // remove primary key reference as we do not want to duplicate the record 
            if (newEntity.Contains("connectionid"))
                newEntity.Attributes.Remove("connectionid");

            if (newEntity.Contains("new_incidentidid"))
            {
                newEntity.Attributes.Remove("new_incidentidid");
                newEntity.Attributes.Add("new_incidentidid", parentCaseRef);
            }

            // remove child case reference if it is there 
            if (newEntity.Contains("new_childcase"))
                newEntity.Attributes.Remove("new_childcase");

            // Get the token number of parent case
            Entity caseEntity = service.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, childCaseRef.Id, new ColumnSet(new[] { "ticketnumber" }));
            if (caseEntity != null)
            {
                newEntity.Attributes.Add("new_childcase", caseEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("ticketnumber"));
            }

            Guid id = service.Create(newEntity);

            //// associate the child case consideration to parent case
            //AssociateConnections(service, new EntityReference("connection", id), parentCaseRef);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have requirement to copy connections from child case to parent case and connection role as 'xxxxx'.

Comment: I could retrieved the connection records from child case using fetch xml. Pending part is to create those connection records in parent case. Please share any other approaches for achieving this requirement.